# Filter DB2 Group based on criteria

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, where-clause, having

I have a data set for multiple versions of a record. In the structure below:

```
ID  Version Date        ActionedBy
1   1       20/08/2018  James
1   2       20/08/2018  Samuel
2   1       20/08/2018  Tom
3   1       20/08/2018  Tom
3   2       20/08/2018  Tom
3   1       20/08/2018  Dave
4   1       20/08/2018  Tom
4   2       20/08/2018  Mike
5   1       20/08/2018  Dave
```

I need a query to return all records that Tom has actioned but not include the ones actioned by Dave. So my result should be:

```
ID
2
4
```

I've grouped on ID but am struggling with the Having clause or sub query to not include records with Dave.

My query is:

```
Select * from events where ActionedBy='Tom' Group By ID Having "NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE"
```

Comment: update your question and addc the expected  result  ..

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? My expected result is already there:

ID
2
4

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be

```
SELECT ID FROM events e
WHERE  ActionedBy = 'Tom'
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  events WHERE ActionedBy = 'Dave' AND ID = e.ID)
```

You do not necessarily need the GROUP BY if Tom occurs only once in a single ID. If not just add it....

Answer (score 0):

I would use `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
select id
from t
where actionedby in ('Tom', 'Dave')
having min(actionedby) = 'Tom' and max(actionedby) = 'Tom';
```

Actually `min()` is sufficient in this case, because `'Tom'` > `'Dave'`.